# Is Egoism of Max Stirner idealization of Free consciousness?

Tags: ontology, existentialism, hegel, nihilism, materialism

In more simple language when Stirner talks about having no fix ideas or not treating ideas as sacred somehow makes it (Egoism of Stirner) having a fix idea itself ? Is creative nothing an idea or reality? Historical references that stirner provided to it was a man in cradle that creates himself with his nothingness with interactions with outer world, history and his individual uniqueness.

Comment: See [Stirner's *Ego*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/max-stirner/#EgoOwn): in a nutshell, the *egosim* is grounded in "liberation from these external constraints [those imposed to children during education] achieving what Stirner calls the self-discovery of mind."

Comment: It didn't answer my question.